# Стадо или стая?

Tags: лексика

Задался недавно вопросом: с точки зрения традиционных различий между "стадом" и "стаей", множество птеродактилей - стадо птеродактилей, или же всё-таки стая?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В контексте вопроса понятия **стадо** и **стая** синонимичны, а "традиционные различия" между ними весьма условны и ограничены большей частью устойчивостью сочетаний (например, *стая волков* и *стадо баранов*), а не широко распространённым ошибочным мнением, будто звери бегают только стадами, а птицы летают только стаями. В литературе запросто встречаются и "стада диких уток" (у А.С. Пушкина) и "стаи крыс" (у С.Я. Маршака), например.

Поэтому вполне допустимы оба варианта употребления: **стая птеродактилей** и **стадо птеродактилей**, а выбор более точного синонима может зависеть от контекста и целей автора.

Answer (score 2):

Увы, мой первый ответ никому понравился, я так и думала. Наверное, на тему лингвистики тоже надо что-то сказать.

**СТАДО,**  ср. 1. **Группа животных, обычно одного вида, ПАСУЩИХСЯ ВМЕСТЕ.** Пасти с. Оленьи стада.  С. баранов (также: пренебр.; неорганизованная толпа; люди, которые слепо, без рассуждений идут за кем-л.).  // Группа животных, птиц, рыб одного вида, ДЕРЖАЩИХСЯ ВМЕСТЕ; стая. Стада белок. Сельдь идёт стадами. 2. только ед. Поголовье сельскохозяйственных животных. Рост племенного стада. 3. Пренебр. Большая неорганизованная группа людей; толпа.

**СТАЯ,**  ж. 1. **Группа животных одного вида (птиц, рыб, собак и т.п.), ДЕРЖАЩИХСЯ ВМЕСТЕ.** С. волков. Журавлиная с. С. галок.  Собираться, сбиваться в стаю, в стаи. 2. кого или какая. Большая группа людей. Ребячья стая. Явиться стаей. С. мальчишек. 3. чего. Масса, скопление, множество чего-л. Стаи туч. Стаями неслись облака.

**По  толковому словарю** можно сделать такой вывод.  Стадо – это группа,  объединенная скорее  ВНЕШНИМИ обстоятельствами, в то время как стаю связывает ВНУТРЕННЕЕ ЕДИНСТВО и определенные отношения/интересы.

**С точки зрения этимологии,**  в слове стадо мы видим **суффикс Д** со значением ПРЕДМЕТНОСТИ (из словаря Черных).

Вероятно, это придает слову "стадо" **определенную устойчивость, внешние границы.**

Answer (score 1):

1. **Можно для начала вспомнить Пушкина:**

Паситесь, мирные народы!

Вас не разбудит чести клич.

К чему **стадам** дары свободы?

Их должно резать или стричь.

Наследство их из рода в роды

Ярмо с гремушками да бич.

**2. А теперь еще что-нибудь почитать…**

Из статьи: Стадо и стая, есть ли разница? https://proza.ru/2013/07/18/1111

«Первое, что приходит в голову: стая – это нечто **вольное, свободное**, даже если эта стая несет какое-то негативное начало, тем не менее, в основе – свобода, воля, собственная ВОЛЯ участника стаи. Теперь стадо. Здесь без лидера, ну просто, никак, иначе стадо разбредется, куда глаза глядят. Лидер может быть и вовсе не из стада (пастух, ковбой, козел, наконец, у стада баранов).

Отсюда появляется предположение, что животные, сбивающиеся в стаи, имеют более **развитый интеллект**, достаточный для того, чтобы увидеть более отдаленную цель. Вот как стая волков выходит на охоту? Они не просто нападают на стадо, но окружают отбившуюся овечку и отгоняют ее подальше от остальных. Тут получается даже какие-то зачатки тактического планирования».

3. **Итак, интеллект – вот что главное.**  Тогда я думаю, что  множество птеродактилей  –  **это скорее стадо птеродактилей.** Ну какой у них может быть интеллект? Они же – неразвитые, первобытные.

Хотя есть другое мнение: «Какой IQ был у птеродактиля? Вот какой точно сказать не могу, но.. . попробуй в то время выжить без соображалки ...»

4. **Тогда, нет – стая, конечно.  Умными они были, эти птеродактили.** Это древние рептилии, которые могли передвигаться по воздуху, иными словами, каким-то образом научились летать. Головной мозг у него был хорошо развит по сравнению с другими животными юрского периода. Эксперты привели убедительные доказательства того, что особенно мозжечок претерпел самое успешное развитие.
   https://dinohistory.ru/kto-takoj-pterodaktil.html

**5. Точно стая, вот здесь даже написано:**

Птеродактили жили **стаями,** строя гнезда на скалах и верхушках высоких деревьев. Пары динозавры создавали на всю жизнь. https://dinobook.ru/dino/xishhniki/pterodaktil-letayushhij-yashher-rossii-avstralii-afriki-i-evropy